# Error: Main method not found in class

Tags: java, class, methods, program-entry-point

This question has been asked on the site before but I haven't been able to figure out what's wrong. I copy and pasted from the Oracle tutorial and it still gives me the error message:

Error: Main method not found in class bicycle.Bicycle, please define the main method as:
   public static void main(String[] args)
or a JavaFX application class must extend javafx.application.Application
C:\Users\Junaid\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.2\executor-snippets\run.xml:53: Java returned: 1
BUILD FAILED (total time: 0 seconds)

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/class.html

```
    package bicycle;


    class Bicycle{

int cadence = 0;
int speed = 0;
int gear = 1;

void changeCadence(int newValue) {
     cadence = newValue;
}

void changeGear(int newValue) {
     gear = newValue;
}

void speedUp(int increment) {
     speed = speed + increment;   
}

void applyBrakes(int decrement) {
     speed = speed - decrement;
}

void printStates() {
     System.out.println("cadence:" +
         cadence + " speed:" + 
         speed + " gear:" + gear);
}
    }

    class BicycleDemo {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
    // Create two different 
    // Bicycle objects
    Bicycle bike1 = new Bicycle();
    Bicycle bike2 = new Bicycle();

    // Invoke methods on 
    // those objects
    bike1.changeCadence(50);
    bike1.speedUp(10);
    bike1.changeGear(2);
    bike1.printStates();

    bike2.changeCadence(50);
    bike2.speedUp(10);
    bike2.changeGear(2);
    bike2.changeCadence(40);
    bike2.speedUp(10);
    bike2.changeGear(3);
    bike2.printStates();
}
}
```

Comment: `BicycleDemo` is the class with the main method not `Bicycle`...

Comment: Did you put both classes into the same file?